# Most efficient way to join two tables on multiple fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm working with an Oracle SQL DB and attempting to join 2 tables together. My issue is that there are 3 different dimensions (4 total fields) upon which the two tables may be joined and I'm looking to identify all records where any one of those methods delivers a match and then pull in a certain field from that 2nd table in those instances.

My current plan is as follows:

```sql
SELECT a.*,
       CASE
       WHEN b.field_1 IS NOT NULL THEN b.field_5
       WHEN c.field_2 IS NOT NULL THEN c.field_5
       WHEN d.field_3 IS NOT NULL THEN c.field_5
       END AS match
FROM   table_1 a
       LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON a.field_1 = b.field_1
       LEFT JOIN table_3 c ON a.field_2 = c.field_2
       LEFT JOIN table_4 d ON a.field_3 = d.field3 AND a.field_4 = d.field4
```

I believe this will give me the results I'm looking for, but I imagine this isn't the most efficient way to accomplish that. Any thoughts on a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

[TL;DR] Your query is fine.

---

- You need to use `JOIN`s to correlate the relationships between the four tables.
- If you want to be able to include rows from the driving table when there are no rows in the related tables then the join wants to be an `OUTER JOIN`.
- If you put the driving table first then it will be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or just `LEFT JOIN`)

You do not have much option on this.

If you want to get the `field_5` values then you either want:

```sql
SELECT a.*,
       b.field_5 AS b_match,
       c.field_5 AS c_match,
       d.field_5 AS d_match
FROM   table_1 a
       LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON a.field_1 = b.field_1
       LEFT JOIN table_3 c ON a.field_2 = c.field_2
       LEFT JOIN table_4 d ON a.field_3 = d.field3 AND a.field_4 = d.field4
```

If you want all the matches.

Or, you want to use your query:

```sql
SELECT a.*,
       CASE
       WHEN b.field_1 IS NOT NULL THEN b.field_5
       WHEN c.field_2 IS NOT NULL THEN c.field_5
       WHEN d.field_3 IS NOT NULL THEN c.field_5  -- Should this be d.field_5?
       END AS match
FROM   table_1 a
       LEFT JOIN table_2 b ON a.field_1 = b.field_1
       LEFT JOIN table_3 c ON a.field_2 = c.field_2
       LEFT JOIN table_4 d ON a.field_3 = d.field3 AND a.field_4 = d.field4
```

If you want to get a single match in preference order of tables `b`, `c` and then `d`.

---

If you are using Oracle 12 or later, a third alternative could be to use `UNION ALL` in a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT a.*, l.field_5
FROM   table_1 a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT 1 AS priority, b.field_5
         FROM   table_2 b
         WHERE  a.field_1 = b.field_1
       UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS priority, c.field_5
         FROM   table_3 c
         WHERE  a.field_2 = c.field_2
       UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS priority, d.field_5
         FROM   table_3 d
         WHERE  a.field_3 = d.field_3
         AND    a.field_4 = d.field_4
       ORDER BY priority ASC
       FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
       ) l
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which may reduce the number of duplicate rows from not having multiple `JOIN`s (that you are potentially ignoring with your `CASE` expression) but you should test whether it does return your desired results and if it would be more or less performant.